# Условия роботы counter-а

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не выходит сделать так что бы counter-up работал только при просмотре, в итоге загружается вместе со страницей. Можно ли вообще модифицировать этот вариант?

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statistics">
  <div class="counter-up">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
    <div class="wrap-flex">
      <div class="counter-cont-1">
        <span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
        <span class="counter bg-count-1" data-count="25000">0</span>
        <span>м<sup>2</sup></span>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-cont-3">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
        <span class="counter bg-count-1" data-count="180000">0</span>
        <span>м<sup>3</sup></span>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-cont-2">
        <span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
        <span class="counter bg-count-1" data-count="7">0</span>
        <span class="year">лет</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
counterAnimate();
$(window).bind('scroll', counterAnimate);

function counterAnimate()
{
  var counterUp = $('.counter-up'),
      win = $(window),
      scroll = win.scrollTop(),
      winHeight = win.height(),
      counterUpPos = counterUp.offset().top,
      counterUpHeight = counterUp.innerHeight();
      
  if(scroll + winHeight >= counterUpPos + counterUpHeight && scroll <= counterUpPos){
    win.unbind('scroll', counterAnimate);
    
    $('.counter').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
      $({
        countNum: $this.text()
      }).animate({
        countNum: countTo
      }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
          $this.text(this.countNum);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.statistics { margin-top: 1000px; } // Для наглядности
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statistics">
  <div class="counter-up">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
    <div class="wrap-flex">
      <div class="counter-cont-1">
        <span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
        <span class="counter bg-count-1" data-count="25000">0</span>
        <span>м<sup>2</sup></span>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-cont-3">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
        <span class="counter bg-count-1" data-count="180000">0</span>
        <span>м<sup>3</sup></span>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-cont-2">
        <span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
        <span class="counter bg-count-1" data-count="7">0</span>
        <span class="year">лет</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```